# How to avoid date change when exporting df to csv format in R?

Tags: r

I am exporting a data frame that contains date name [format: yyyy-mm-dd] as columns to csv using the following command.`write.csv(df, "E:\\df.csv")`
[image: original data frame]
when viewing this in excel the col names are replaced by ######## but I still can see it in the formula bar as shown but with format change[dd-mm-yyyy].

[image: view in excel]

However the problem arises when I try to load it back in R using the following command `mj<-read.csv("E:\\df.csv")`
now the column values have changed.
[image: imported data frame from csv]

I need the data frames exported in a format that will allow me to access and run it for my analyses. I have over 100 of these some of which took over 2 hour to compile. I can't afford doing this repeatedly.
How can I avoid this from happening? or is there any other file format I can use?
PS. using `save(df, file = "df.RData")` also is not satisfactory.

Comment: In my experience, Excel showing `#######` means that the data is wider than the column can currently show. Widen the column (`C` in this case) and you should see the data.

Comment: Are the dates used as column headers? If so, they are prefixed with "X" when read back into R, because R doesn't like column names to start with a number. If you want to preserve them, use the `check.names = FALSE` argument to `read.csv`.

Comment: @neilfws this works great. just  will be needing to remove an extra indexing column. Thanks for the help.

Comment: The "x" column is added to the file when you save it; if you set `row.names = FALSE` when saving the file you shouldn't get the "x" 'indexing' column @hat6ytrs, e.g. `write.csv(df, "E:\\df.csv", row.names = FALSE)`